# Wamp server and php files

Tags: php

i saved some .php files on wamp\www . But i can’t see my projects on localhost? what should i do.? please help someone..

Comment: What can you see on localhost? Is the wamp page loading?

Comment: LEFT click on the WAMP icon in your task bar and select  WWW Directory. Do you see the projects you saved?

Comment: Yes the wamp page is loading. i could see the files in WWW Directory, the problem is "My projects" is empty in the browser..!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wamp determines a project to be a folder within your www folder.

i.e.

```
C:\
    wamp\
        www\
            project1\
                 index.php
            project2\
                 index.php
```

will have two projects...

The wamp homepage isn't necessary to view your php files...

If you have a file at `C:\wamp\www\runme.php` you can go to the URL `http://localhost/runme.php` to run your script.

If `http://localhost/` isn't displaying the wamp local homepage, make sure wamp is running, the icon is in your task bar and white (Thanks JohnP).

Comment: The icon is actually white. If one of the services is down, it can be yellow or red.

Comment: Thank u Jacob,..wamp is running, usualy its seems like my browser shows the php files. your ANSWER worked for me,in the sense i could run my php files...still "my projects" is empty..

Comment: @rakzz do you have folders in your www folder.

Comment: No i dont have any folder inside it.

Comment: i created seperate folders inside WWW/ and it worked for me.. Thank you Jacob.