# PHP Login System Error. Logging is not possible

Tags: php

I need help building a PHP login form this is my index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","usbw","login");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "MySQLi Connection was not established:"  . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

    $sql = "SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email=? AND user_pass=?";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli_prepare($sql)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $pass);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

        // Checking if the user was valid
        if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
            header('Location: loggedin.html');
            exit;
        } else {
            header('Location: index.html');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>



<html>

<head>

<title>User Login</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post">

<table width="500" align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">

<tr align="center">

<td colspan="3"><h2>User Login</h2></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Email</b></td>

<td><input type="text" name="email" required="required"/></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Password:</b></td>

<td><input type="password" name="pass" required="required"></td>

</tr>

<tr align="center">

<td colspan="3">

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

There error I get with this code is in the picture in this link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/vitdqwcv5dip20s/Untitled.png?dl=0

I can't login with the system I've builded now and I need help building it. I think the code is split after the > 0 but someone else need to look in to it I'm just a starter with php

Comment: you don't need `mysqli_real_escape_string()` if you're using a prepared statement.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php probably outputting before header.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so what would my code look like if that is removed?

Comment: just remove `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ` and the closing `)` for both.

Comment: @Fred-ii- after that it should work?

Comment: `http://` not `file://` Also remove the escaping and your passwords should be hashed.

Comment: try it out and see. TBH, I don't know what the image looks like, so if people are saying access as `http://localhost/file.xxx` rather than `c:///file.xxx` then that's the issue. However, you don't need that escaping function as I stated.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm accessing the file straight from a folder on my computer. Is this wrong?

Comment: `.html` files can be accessed directly into a web browser. PHP / `.php` on the other hand requires a webserver/PHP be installed and accessed as a webserver and not as a folder. the Wampserver documentation should have contained this information and to be accessed as `http://localhost` since a server connection is required and needs it to parse PHP directives. Depending on the location of the install, usually it is the `www` folder that you put your PHP files in.

Comment: I have xampp installed on my laptop and running it. Where do I need to put the files? because they ain't working tried many tutorials @Fred-ii-

Comment: $mysqli_prepare() that doesn't look like a valid function call.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308571/wamp-server-and-php-files for your wamp set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screen shot :

You are not using this file in your wamp.

If you are not using it under wamp then your PHP file treat as HTML.

Comment: How can I use it as wamp as I said I'm just a starter with PHP

Comment: so I need to place my php file in my phpMyAdmin folder or am I wrong?

Comment: No it's not like that. Please refer above manual. And google about how to install wamp

Comment: You need to not use the `file` protocol. It is processed as a plain text file that way. With the `http` protocol it should be read by your WAMP and processed as PHP.

Comment: I'm using xampp from what I understand is it thecsamecas wamp